# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when there is no value in second

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to do a update query and struggling to handle the DateTime field.

The frontend form is built with Twig template as it is a symfony application. I import the value from the database and show it in the form like below.

```
<input id="EventDateTime" type="datetime-local" value="{{  event.EventDateTime|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}"  data-field="EventDateTime" data-field-required="true" />
```

The input field sometimes presented with the second value and sometimes without the second value. (See Picture below)

[image]

When there is a value in second then the update query works fine. but when there is no value in seconds i get the error **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."**

Even when I set value of second as 0 0 then also I get the same error.

That is  when  `EventDateTime=2023-02-28T11:30:01,` update is sucessful ;
But when `EventDateTime=2021-10-01T18:00` then I get this error - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The code in my controller file is like this

```
$currentEvent->EventDateTime = $event->EventDateTime;
```

here `$event->EventDateTime` is the value i am receiving from twig template. How can i handle this field so it works without the second value. The database is sql server

Comment: `$currentEvent->EventDateTime = $event->EventDateTime;` Thats doing no checking and no attempt at conversion. Are you expecting some mgic perhaps?

Comment: i have tried this  - date_format($event->EventDateTime, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');  but doesnot work. and i get same error.  So i skipped that part. Ps there is no reason to be rude just because you know better than some poor fellow

Comment: I assume something you do must let the calendar return a datetime without the seconds. Would it not be simpler to make the calendar always ask for the seconds or default the seconds to `00`

Comment: It will be comparatively difficult for users  if the calendar asks for second value. and I get the same error  even when the second  value is 00

Comment: Symfony app? Why are you not using a Symfony form type? Is `event` a Doctrine managed Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will need to do a little twiddling with the date you get back from the browser.

Here is one suggestion. This should work whichever version of the 2 datetime formats you could get

```
$input = '2021-10-01T18:00';    // what you get from browser

// convert to a datetime object from which ever version of date and time you get given
if ( strlen($input) == 16 ){
    $d = ( new DateTime() )->createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $input);
} else {
    $d = ( new DateTime() )->createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $input);
}
// use this datetime in the database
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

> [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/iUEDU)

Comment: Thank You. That do the trick. I also had to add this line 'use DateTime;' in my controller to use the function.